# Haramain situation at time of fatamid caliphate?

Tags: history, sunni, masjid-al-haram

What was situation at masjid-al-haram and masjid Nabvi(Peace be Upon him) during fatmid caliphate? Was there sunni administration(Imam,muazzin etc) or shia administration at that time?

Comment: The fatmid caliphate never seem to have existed in Makkah and Madinah:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimid_Caliphate

Comment: @FahadUddin I didn't find anything useful to answer the question in the Wikipedia site you've shared.